# Cannot change Apple ID into App Store

Tags: macos, app-store, apple-id

I use Mac OS: 10.9.2. When I update Xcode to 5.1.1 the App Store ask the apple ID. I had log out the current apple ID and login my account but it also ask pass word of the old apple ID(I can not click into the field Apple ID to change the name). Please help me to change apple id or delete the old.

[image]

**Edit**

Finally, I can resolved this. I **move to trash** all the versions of Xcode which I have in Application. Then go to App Store to install new version of Xcode with my Apple ID.

Answer (score 37):

### Reason:

This happens because *the app was downloaded using another Apple ID* and xcode is tied to that account.

### How to solve this ?

- Sign in into Mac App Store with *“your current ID account”* and check under *Purchases* menu, whether you have xcode.
- Also check in **System Preferences » App Store »** What ID shows below “Automatic download apps purchased...”
- If xcode is present under your current ID Purchases (grayed out saying INSTALLED), feel free to erase the app from your HD. An install button must be shown after and you can download and update the app again.
- If the above doesn't work, you can *get rid of the greyed out Apple ID email* by making following selection 
   `Applications » xcode (right click on Show Package Contents) » Contents » and delete the file inside “_MASReceipt” folder (do a backup before just in case)`. 
  xcode will still work, you must get rid of the grayed login name.This will work if xcode is already in your curent Apple ID

Comment: `"Update Unavailable with This Apple ID: This update is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled."` It still doesn't let me update the app.

Comment: Perhaps the reason is, the Receipt Validation of my app is rather strong.

Comment: @Rao - you are correct update using the same Apple ID that downloaded the app.

Comment: @NagaR thanks, ended up having to delete the app and re-installing.

Comment: @NagaR thanks buddy "deleting the file inside “_MASReceipt” folder"" did the trick.No need to delete the app and re-installing it.Just delete file inside   “_MASReceipt” folder".......cheers :)

Comment: HD == "Hard Disk" ?

Comment: I was trying to rename the app and to move the app in other directory and App Store still saw the app as an update and prevent me from reinstall the app with my new user. Delete the file in _MASReceipt did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19):

I was having the same issue.This happens because the app was downloaded using another Apple ID and xcode is tied to that account. If you installs new app then there wont be any issue.

**Solution**

1. Go to Applications -> xCode -> Click Show Packaged Content ->
   Content -> _MASReceipt -> Receipt. Delete this receipt file. Do not
   worry xcode will still work.
2. Now try to update xcode from app store. You will be able to get app
   store id login popup without grayed apple id.

Still you might face some issues as I faced. I got this error. If you are also facing some issue then continue following 3,4 and 5 steps.

[image]

3. Go to application -> Move xCode to trash.
4. Go to trash -> Put Back xCode.
5. Go to app store and update the xCode.

It worked for me :)

Refer :- http://www.valiant-ny.com/2014/06/grayed-out-apple-id-explained/

Comment: Apple's support site tries to get you to update MacOS and have it do some automatic update horrible sauce. This is wayyyyy better

Answer (score 0):

For me, the locked-in Apple ID was from a former employee. Following steps eventually fixed it for me:

- Go to Settings » Users & Groups » **Delete the old user account**
- Start Disk Utility and **Repair Disk Permissions**
- In the App Store menu, hit **Store » Sign Out / Sign In**

Answer (score -1):

There's a "Sign Out" option in the App Store app under the "Store" menu.

It looks like this:

[image: how to sign out]

Comment: Yep. I had sign out and then sig in with my Apple ID but when I update again the App Store also ask password with the old Apple ID

Comment: Unfortunately, you'd have to delete the apps that were downloaded with the old Apple ID.  More information can be found [in this thread at discussion.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24230303#24230303).

Comment: The behavior may depend on the version of MacOS X that you're using. I had exactly the same problem as the OP, right down to the old AppleID being a Gmail address, except that I'm using MacOS X 10.1. Signing out and signing in again solved the problem for me. This answer may not help everyone, but it's certainly not wrong.